# Using Mathf.Clamp without effecting y axis.

Tags: c#, camera, transform, positioning, math-functions

I have a script that makes my camera follow the mouse. Works fine but I want the camera to only be able to move so far so I used this.

transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, 1.5f, -1.4f), 0, -10);

It works to stop the camera from moving too far on the x axis but it also froze the y axis completely. I tried using another Mathf.Clamp again using transform.position.y but it made no difference. Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: It looks like you're just passing a hardcoded `0` in for `y`. Shouldn't that be `transform.position.y`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want the same values for `y` and `z` that you already have:

```
transform.position = new Vector3(Mathf.Clamp(transform.position.x, 1.5f, -1.4f),
                                 transform.position.y,
                                 transform.position.z);
```

This way you're only changing the `x` value.